# Is the normal linear model analysis "rotation-invariant"? On alr vs ilr

Tags: linear-model, compositional-data

Abstractly speaking, are the methods of regression and analysis of variance in normal linear models, along with hypothesis tests and confidence intervals, etc., "rotation-invariant"?

In particular, when doing compositional data analysis, it is often said that the 'alr'-transformation is no good since it's not an isometry, unlike the ilr transformation.

So I am wondering whether you can use the alr transformation for regression-like analysis, or is it not rotation-invariant, thus requiring ilr?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "rotation" and "rotation-invariant" because these have  several plausible meanings in such settings and the answer is either "yes" or "no" depending on what you mean!  In particular, it is difficult to reconcile any discussion of *rotations* (which, by definition, preserve Euclidean distances) with the ALR, which is a non-linear (whence non-isometric) transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The ALR transform is not rotationally invariant. Representations of objects/data/distributions change dependent on which variable is taken as the denominator of the transform. Changing which variable is in the denominator is equivalent to a rotation in the Aitchison geometry.

That said, the ALR transform is actually quite useful for regression analysis (just be careful and don't try to do many calculations or comparisons with the coefficients as the ALR does not preserve metric concepts - not perturbation invariant where perturbation is the log-ratio version of translation).